# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in json function

Tags: node.js, json

I am going to build a weather data pipeline that starts with an Internet of Things (IoT) device, utilizes a message queue to receive and deliver data, leverages a serverless function to move the data to a data warehouse and then create a dashboard that displays the information. I am getting error in function.

```
/** 
 * Background Cloud Function to be triggered by PubSub. 
 * 
 * @param{  
   object
}event The Cloud Functions event. 
 * @param{  
   function
}callback The callback function. 
 */ 
exports.subscribe = function (event,
callback){  
   const BigQuery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery'); 
  const projectId = "iot2analytics-ca4"; //Enter your project ID here 
  const datasetId = "weatherData"; //Enter your BigQuery dataset name here 
  const tableId = "weatherDatatable"; //Enter your BigQuery table name here -- make sure it is setup correctly 
  const PubSubMessage = event.data; 
  // Incoming data is in JSON format 
  const incomingData = PubSubMessage.data ? Buffer.from(PubSubMessage.data,
   'base64'   ).toString():"{'sensorID':'na','timecollected':'1/1/1970 00:00:00','zipcode':'00000','latitude':'0.0','longitude':'0.0','temperature':'-273','humidity':'-1','dewpoint':'-273','pressure':'0'}"   ;
  const jsonData = JSON.parse(incomingData); 
  var rows =   [  
      jsonData
   ]   ; 

  console.log(`Uploading data:$   {  
      JSON.stringify(rows)
   }   `   ); 

  // Instantiates a client 
  const bigquery = BigQuery(   {  
      projectId:projectId
   }   ); 

  // Inserts data into a table 
  bigquery 
    .dataset(datasetId) 
    .table(tableId) 
    .insert(rows) 
    .then((foundErrors) =>   {  
      rows.forEach((row) => console.log('Inserted:', row)); 

      if (foundErrors && foundErrors.insertErrors != undefined) { 
        foundErrors.forEach((err) => { 
            console.log('      Error:', err); 
        }) 
      } 
    }) 
    .catch((err) => { 
      console.error('      ERROR:',
      err);
   }   ); 
  //   [  
      END bigquery_insert_stream
   ]   callback();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using single quotes to wrap the string in the JSON object which is not allowed with standard formats. Please replace the single quotes with double quotes and then stringify your object. Here, use this

```
let temp = {
    "sensorID":"na",
      "timecollected":"1/1/1970 00:00:00",
      "zipcode":"00000",
      "latitude":"0.0",
      "longitude":"0.0",
      "temperature":"-273",
      "humidity":"-1",
      "dewpoint":"-273",
      "pressure":"0"
    }
    temp = JSON.stringify(temp)
    const incomingData = PubSubMessage.data ? Buffer.from(PubSubMessage.data,
       'base64'   ).toString(): temp;
```